# How to get dbId of all model elements?

Tags: autodesk-viewer

I need to get all the dbId elements of the model for my project. I looked at all the ways to get dbId, but none of them solved my problem. I load two models and I need to compare the differences to display them. If the two models differ from each other in the size of one wall, then I must paint this wall in a different color. My solution algorithm looks like this: I load 2 models in one scene, after which I try to get the dbId of all the elements of the two models, and if there is a difference among the received dbId, then I paint it in a different color. I can't get a list of all dbId.

```
[Link on of my code][1]
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KENKrE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below:

```
var frags = _viewer.model.getFragmentList().fragments.fragId2dbId;
frags.forEach(function(frag){
  frag.forEach(function(dbId){
    if (dbId<0) return;
     dbids.push(dbId);
  });
});
```

Alternatively you can iterate the instance tree via the Model Derivative APIs to process the comparison on server side - see more details [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/get-all-dbid-without-enumerating-model-hierarchy)

Comment: Thank you very much, your help is invaluable. 
I also wanted to ask why, when loading two models into one scene, I can change the color of only one of them, and I can not get access to the second.

Comment: I use this code, but it does not work correctly, maybe there is another method for coloring the transferred item?
Here, the DBID array contains a list of dbId that I pass to the setThemingColor functions for coloring, but it does not work, but if I pass one element of the array, then everything works fine, what is the reason?

const BLUE = new THREE.Vector4(0, 0, 0.5, 0.5);

 DBID.forEach(dbId => {
    viewer.setThemingColor(dbId, BLUE);
  })

Comment: if you look at its doc `setThemingColor` takes one single dbid instead of an array at a time and with the latest [v6.5](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/viewer-release-notes-v-65) it now accepts a recursive flag to color the child notes.

Comment: Great, I understand you. Or maybe there is another solution, for example, another method for painting an array of transferred objects or for mass hiding? For me the main highlight a great item and it does not matter, I'll do it with the help of paint or by concealment (insulation).

Comment: For example, I have two models, I load the first one and get an array of its dbId, suppose such an array: [1, 2, 4, 7, 8]. Then I load the second model and get, suppose, such an array: [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8]. Now I compare these two arrays and after comparing I get a new array [3, 4, 5, 6]. I have to select the final array, I think the isolation method (hide) is suitable for this.

Comment: In addition, there is a big problem, the reason for which I don’t understand, when I download the second model, I can change its color, hide it and perform any other function with only one of them, it’s impossible to access the second one.

P. S.
I manage to change the color of two or more elements using the current method, but this method can work from 3, and maybe from 7 times, the reason for this behavior is also unclear.

Comment: Try access different models in their array via `viewer.impl.modelQueue()`